# StringWriter is not disposed along all exception paths

Tags: c#, stringwriter

I am working with a `StringWriter` which I am passing to a method to write values in a `foreach` loop. I believe this is causing the generation of two warnings:

> CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'ToCsvService.ToCsv()', object 'sw' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'sw' before all references to it are out of scope.

and

> CA2202 : Microsoft.Usage : Object 'sw' can be disposed more than once in method 'ToCsvService.ToCsv()'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.

```
public string ToCsv()
{
    IEnumerable<string> props = GetProperties();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); // first warning here
    sw.WriteLine(GetHeadings(props));
    WriteValues(props, sw);

    sw.Close();
    string returnCsv = sw.ToString();
    sw.Dispose(); // second warning here

    return returnCsv;
}
```

I've left out `GetProperties()` from the list of methods called as it didn't seem pertinent.

```
private string GetHeadings(IEnumerable<string> props)
{
    string headings = String.Join(",",
        props.Select(prop =>
            _headings.ContainsKey(prop) ? _headings[prop] : prop));

    return headings;
}

private void WriteValues(IEnumerable<string> props, StringWriter sw)
{
    foreach (object obj in _collection)
    {
        var x = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(pi => props.Contains(pi.Name))
            .Select(pi =>
                _format.ContainsKey(pi.Name)
                ? String.Format("{0:" + _format[pi.Name] + "}",
                                pi.GetGetMethod().Invoke(obj, null))
                : pi.GetGetMethod().Invoke(obj, null).ToString());

        string values = String.Join<string>(",", x);

        sw.WriteLine(values);
    }
}
```

Why are these warnings being generated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code allows for the possibility that a thrown exception causes execution to skip over the statement that closes your `StringWriter`. You want to ensure that, before an exception causes execution to leave `ToCSV`, you close `sw`.

The easiest way to handle this is with a `using` block. An object constructed within a `using` clause is guaranteed to be disposed before the scope of the block is exited:

```
public string ToCsv()
{
    IEnumerable<string> props = GetProperties();
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        sw.WriteLine(GetHeadings(props));
        WriteValues(props, sw);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to call both `Close` and `Dispose` on the StringWriter. Just `Dispose` is enough.

In general, you'll want to wrap a `using` block around the creation and use of all objects that implement `IDisposable` (as `StringWriter` does). That'll ensure that, no matter what exceptions get thrown, the object is always disposed of properly.

Comment: Since it's guaranteed to be disposed I am guessing that's why you don't have a `sw.Close()`.

Comment: @ahsteele: yes. `Dispose` will call `Close`.

Answer (score 3):

The second warning is because StringWriter.Close() calls StringWriter.Dispose(), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.close.aspx , so you are calling Dispose twice.

The first warning is because if there is an exception after you new StringWriter() you don't have any catch statements to call Dispose on it.  I would suggest rewriting your code to be

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) { 
    sw.WriteLine(GetHeadings(props));
    WriteValues(props, sw);
    return sw.ToString();
}
```